# If $\beta = \left( 1 \;3 \;5 \;7 \;9 \;8 \;6\right)\left(2\; 4 \;10\right) \in S_{10}$, what is the smallest integer such that $\beta^n = \beta^{-5}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I manually found that $\beta^{-5} = \left(1\; 5 \;9 \;6 \;3 \;7 \;8\right)\left( 2 \;10 \;4\right)$. The nice thing is that since beta is composed of two disjoint cycles, so I know that $\beta^n = \left( 1 \;3 \;5 \;7 \;9 \;8 \;6\right)^n\left(2\; 4 \;10\right)^n$. Now I just tried to find an $n$ such that $\left(2\; 4 \;10\right)^n = \left( 2 \;10 \;4\right)$ after finding one I would check to see if $\left( 1 \;3 \;5 \;7 \;9 \;8 \;6\right)^n= \left(1\; 5 \;9 \;6 \;3 \;7 \;8\right)$. Clearly $n=2$ works and luckily $\left( 1 \;3 \;5 \;7 \;9 \;8 \;6\right)^2= \left(1\; 5 \;9 \;6 \;3 \;7 \;8\right)$. So I can conclude that $\beta^2 = \beta^{-5}$.

---

My question is how do I check is $n=2$ is indeed the smallest integer. All I showed so far is that $\beta^2 = \beta^{-5}$ and nothing about if 2 is the lowest value. One possibility is to consider the integers from -2 to 1 and try to show that those fail. But is there a better way to do a question like this.

Comment: You said that you already manually computed $\beta^{-5}$. Presumably, along the way, you also calculated the exponents $-1$, $-2$, $-3$, and $-4$?

Comment: Note that $\beta^{21}=(1)$ and it is the smallest such integer.

Comment: What do you mean by smallest *integer*? Would $n=-5$, $n=-26$ etc. count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the smallest $n$ such that the order of $\beta$ divides $n+5$.

Since you have disjoint cycles of length $7$ and $3$, the order is $21$. Hence, $n = 16$.

Comment: So $n = 2$ also works. Since $(2+5) | 21$

Comment: No, it has to be the other way around. You need $21 | n+5$. Note that for an element $g$ in a group $G$, $g^n = e$ if and only if $\operatorname{ord}(g) | n$.

Comment: But I have shown that $\beta^2 = \beta^{-5}$. So while $n=16$ does provide me with an integer solution, it is by no means the smallest.

Comment: @Stan $(2 \; 4 \; 10)^{-5} = (2 \; 4 \; 10)$ you made a mistake in your computation